# Image button in ActionLink MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, actionlink

How to put image instead text in ActionLink button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit-link", "Edit", new { id=use.userID })
```

So how to change text "Edit-link" to image?

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

do like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit")" id="@use.userID">
<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/someimage.png")" />
</a>
```

or pass both **action** and **controller** name by using other override:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Controller")" id="@use.userID">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/someimage.png")" />
    </a>
```

### UPDATE:

You can also  create a [custom Html Helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs), and can reuse it in any View in application:

```
namespace MyApplication.Helpers
{
  public static class CustomHtmlHelepers
  {
    public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string action, string controller, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes,string imageSrc)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        img.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(imageSrc));
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a") { InnerHtml = img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) };
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
        anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());

    }
  }
}
```

and use it in View:

```
@using MyApplication.Helpers;

@Html.ImageActionLink("LinkText","ActionName","ControllerName",null,null,"~/images/untitled.png")
```

### Output HTML:

```
<a href="/ControllerName/ActionName">
  <img src="/images/untitled.png">
</a>
```

Comment: you have to pass your controllername here

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Edit-link","Edit", new { id=use.userID }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Edit-link", "<img src=\"/Contents/img/logo.png\" ... />"))
```

or

[image]

Comment: so you put ...Replace("Edit-link", "img-source-here"?

Comment: Parser Error Message: "<" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Comment: I fix Parser Error Message, but then appears this error: A route named 'Edit' could not be found in the route collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Edit Link","Edit",new {id = item.EId })">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/iconfinder_new-24_103173.png")" style="height:20px;width:20px;color:blue" title="Edit" />
 </a>
```

Try this code. It will add an image linked to the `Edit()` action with the `id` set.

Comment: That should probably be `new {id = user.userID }` for consistency with the OP’s sample code.