# How to make links clickable in an image?

Tags: css, html

I have some text and links in an image. I want to use this image in html page and want to make all available link clickable.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this with the help of CSS. keep that text and link on image by aligning using Position, Margin, Padding fields.

Comment: If you have control over the image and text, then gkrishy's comment is the correct answer, if you don't have control over the image, then BMahmoudi's answer is correct to use html maps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image button in ActionLink MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535704/image-button-in-actionlink-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You should either use whole image as clickable like

```
<a href="URL"><img src="Path" /></a>
```

Or you could use `flash` file instead which will help you what you want.

Comment: I have lots of links in image. I can't use <a href="URL"><img src="Path" /></a>

Comment: As @BMahmoudi mentions, image maps existed in the HTML spec long before flash and any other plugin technology came along. -1 for suggesting to use a plugin technology when a basic html implementation will suffice

Comment: image map works for me !

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image Maps. Ther is an instruction here.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: How can I get position(coordinates) of links from an image?

Comment: @PramodRana Use ruler in Photoshop.